# Azure DevOps OAuth organization policies API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

is there a way to know via API what is the organization policy for 3rd party OAuth requests?

i want to know if i should ask my user to authenticate with his credentials or generate PAT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to know via API what is the organization policy for 3rd
> party OAuth requests?

You can use this api which I fetched from F12:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{YourOrgName}/_settings/organizationPolicy?__rt=fps&__ver=2
```

The response would contain the info about `Application Connection Policies`:

```
               "ms.vss-admin-web.organization-policies-data-provider": {
                    "policies": {
                        "applicationConnection": [
                            {
                                "policy": {
                                    "name": "Policy.DisallowOAuthAuthentication",
                                    "value": false,
                                    "effectiveValue": true,
                                    "parentPolicy": {
                                        "name": "Policy.DisallowOAuthAuthentication",
                                        "value": false,
                                        "effectiveValue": true,
                                        "isValueUndefined": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "learnMoreLink": "https://aka.ms/vstspolicyoauth",
                                "description": "Third-party application access via OAuth",
                                "applicableServiceHost": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "policy": {
                                    "name": "Policy.DisallowSecureShell",
                                    "value": false,
                                    "effectiveValue": true,
                                    "isValueUndefined": true,
                                    "parentPolicy": {
                                        "name": "Policy.DisallowSecureShell",
                                        "value": false,
                                        "effectiveValue": true,
                                        "isValueUndefined": true
                                    }
                                },
                                "learnMoreLink": "https://aka.ms/vstspolicyssh",
                                "description": "SSH authentication",
                                "applicableServiceHost": 1
                            }
                        ]...
```

The **effectiveValue**(not `value` node) node under corresponding `policy` node should represent whether you enable/disable the policies above in your pic. E.g: The `effectiveValue` node under first `policy` node would be `false` if the `Third-party application access via OAuth` is disabled.

Comment: i still need the user to authenticate to get this data. I want to query this before so i can offer different type of authentication - OAuth vs PAT

Comment: @bk Sorry but I'm afraid there's no other rest api or azure devops extension api can be used ro get the organization policy info. So far only this undocumented one can access the info you want.